# Office 2010 missing macros

Tags: macros, microsoft-office-2010

I'm running a newly installed Office 2010 installation on a Windows XP machine, but whenever I try using some of its features, like equations in Word, I get this message:

> The function you are attempting to run contains macros or content that
>   requires macro language support. When this software was installed, you (or
>   your administrator) chose not to install support for macros or controls.

I have tried reinstallig, and opening the control panel to add Visual Basic to Office's characteristics. Of course when installing, I didn't disable macros at all (to my knowledge)

I've tried almost all solutions listed on forums found by searching the problem on Google...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across your question when trying to solve this myself, because I messed in the registry some time ago and I remember that I had disabled VBA a while ago without know that this would disable equations.

This approach worked for me:

1. Make sure that the Visual Basic for Applications feature of Office is installed.
2. Make sure that there is no `VbaOff` entry in the registry under the Office key.

However, if the problem lies deeper (more likely for you), you need to:

1. Completely remove Office.
2. **Remove the Office keys from the registry** which were left behind (seach for Office keys).
3. Do a full non-customized installation of Office, or at least make sure that VBA is installed along...

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the steps given below:

1. Close all the office applications.
2. Click on Start -> Control Panel -> Programs-> Programs and Features.
3. Click on Microsoft Office 2010 and click on change.
4. Click on continue for Add/remove features.
5. Expand Office Shared Features.
6. Click on the little arrow attached to Visual Basic for Application and select Run from my    Computer-> continue.
7. Click close once the configuration window and try to open word documents.